# implements blocked interfaces

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I would like to implement another interface in this interface (Ifirst). Problem is very big because they are blocked and is not possible to write "implements Isecond" Maybe you know what I have to do to implement this in another way? Because this problem is very hard of course look easy but is really difficult.

```
public interface Ifirst {

}

public interface Isecond {

}
```

They are blocked and I can use them but I`am not able to edit.

I get answ - > Create a third that extends first and second and don't add anything to it

I get correct answer, maybe is not the best way but is working. I gave you points for help Topic [closed] "Create a third that extends first and second and don't add anything to it."

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"? And why do you need to edit the interface in order to implement it?

Comment: " implement another interface in this interface " No. An interface can **never implement**.

Comment: A public interface can be implemented anywhere so it is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Sounds like it has nothing to do with interfaces but everything to do with file access.

Comment: Maybe I have to make special interface which can make unreal "implements" I know this difficult question because this school problem and I`m not able to do it but I have to.

Comment: You have got blocked edit in interfaces, but you have to make relation between interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can't use `implements`, the rule is:

- An interface `extends` other interfaces.
- A class `implements` other interfaces.
- A class `extends` another non-`final` class.

If you can't modify `Ifirst` and `Isecond`, that's the way.

```
public interface Ithird extends Ifirst, Isecond {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how to **extend** an interface?

```
 public interface Iseond extends Ifirst {

 }
```

Interfaces extend other interfaces.

Classes extend other classes and implement interfaces.

Comment: I think this is what he is looking for. Classes implementing Isecond must implement methods from Isecond and Ifirst this way.

Comment: @Thilo this way I know it but as I write I'm not able to edit first or second and there is a problem.